# Using Leibniz Integral Rule on infinite region

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to take the derivative with respect to $a$ of some function $I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(a,x)dx$.  I would like to make sure that I am using the [Leiniz Integral Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) correctly.  Various web sources indicate a set of conditions that must hold for $f(x,a)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,a)}{\partial a}$ when integration is done over infinite region.  From reading [this source](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf) (see Theorem 10.3 on page 13) the conditions that $f(x,a)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,a)}{\partial a}$ must obey are:

1. $f(x,a)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,a)}{\partial a}$ are continuous over $x\in[0,\infty)$ and around $a$ that we are interested in.
2. There exists an integrable function (over $x$) $g(x)$ such that $|\frac{\partial f(x,a)}{\partial a}|\leq g(x)$.
3. There exists an integrable function (over $x$) $h(x)$ such that $|f(x,a)|\leq h(x)$.

Integrable here means $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx<\infty$.

However, [another source](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~rharron/teaching/MAT203/LeibnizRule.pdf) seems to omit condition 3 above.  I am wondering which source is correct.  If there are "both correct", when is condition 3 necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Revisiting this question, I now realize that the author of the  paper is using the uniform convergence of the integral, not the dominated convergence theorem, to justify differentiating under the integral sign.

A proof can be found in the first supplement to the textbook [*Introduction to Real Analysis*](http://digitalcommons.trinity.edu/mono/7/) by William F. Trench. It's Theorem 11 on page 18.

Condition 2 is the M-test for uniform convergence, which can only be used if $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} f(x,a) \, dx  $  is absolutely convergent.

The uniform converge of $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x,a) \, dx$ is not one of the assumptions in the proof, but rather it's proven that it's a consequence of $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} f(x,a) \, dx  $ converging uniformly for values of $a$ in some closed interval.

---

Those are sufficient but not necessary conditions.  <s>Basically they mimic Theorem 2 at the following link without any reference to measure theory or Lebesgue integration.  Condition 3 from your source is basically saying that $f(x,a)$ is Lebesgue integrable.</s>

http://planetmath.org/differentiationundertheintegralsign

I prefer the related approach (when possible) of expressing the integral as an iterated integral and then switching the order of integration.  Justifying switching the order of integration is usually easier.

Comment: I think Theorem 2 in the link you posted works well for my problem, thank you!  However, I just have one more clarification: by Theorem 2 in the link the conditions 2 and 3 in the statement of the theorem in my question can be loosened to hold only over the region $x\in[0,\infty)$.  Does that seem right to you?