# Supposedly Leibniz integral rule is only allowed for upper limit $< \infty$

Tags: calculus

The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) supposedly requests $< \infty$ for the upper limit:

> (...) an integral of the form $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt$, where $-\infty<a(x)$, $b(x)<\infty$, (...)

However, I can still do something like this:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} t^4e^{-xt} \text{dt}
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}x^4} e^{-xt} \text{dt}
= \frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}x^4} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt} \text{dt}
= \frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}x^4} x^{-1}
= 24x^{-5}$

Why does this still work? Is this another rule?

Comment: Remember that improper integrals are _limits_ of proper integrals.  Therefore, this can be reinterpreted as "when can I interchange limits and derivatives?" for which i find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409178/can-i-exchange-limit-and-differentiation-for-a-sequence-of-smooth-functions)

Comment: The three conditions listed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/298458/620957) are sufficient.